# Custom Static Page to Display Blog Posts in Excerpt Non-Singular Form (is_singular not working?)

Tags: theme-development, query-posts, homepage

I have been trying to change my code from my index.php to a custom page template instead as this is better practice I have been told.

The original code for the index.php does not work anymore so I have tried to this code, and it retrieves the posts correctly - however it appears to be retrieving the posts in 'Singular' format and displays all of the content rather than an excerpt.

Here is the current homepage php code:

```
<h3>Read Our Latest Cleaning Posts</h3>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">
            <div id="blog-homepage">
            <?php
            $query_options = array('posts_per_page' => 3);
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_options ); 

            while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); 
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

            endwhile;
            the_posts_navigation();
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

And here is the template-parts/content file:

```
<div class="article-container">
    <?php scores_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="post-text">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;

        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :
            ?>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php
                scores_posted_on();
                scores_posted_by();
                ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
        the_content( sprintf(
            wp_kses(
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'scores' ),
                array(
                    'span' => array(
                        'class' => array(),
                    ),
                )
            ),
            get_the_title()
        ) );
        else :
            the_excerpt();
        endif;

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'scores' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
         scores_entry_footer();
        else: ?>
            <div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
    </div><!-- end of the text content container (excl. img tmb) -->
</article></div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

From what I gather the 'is_singular' is resulting in true, therefore causing it to display all the content. What am I doing wrong here?

**--> Bonus:** *the code that did work on the index.php page but not on the custom template:*

```
<h3>Read Our Latest Cleaning Posts</h3>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">
            <div id="blog-homepage">
                <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :

            if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
                ?>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>
                <?php
            endif;

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>
            </div>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: "I have been trying to change my code from my index.php to a custom page template instead as this is better practice I have been told." Could you elaborate on the context? This is almost certainly not true.

Comment: Hmm.. I was doing research on different forums + websites and they mentioned index.php should be the last resort and not used to place all of the main homepage/landing page code.
When using index.php as the main homepage I also could not find a way to update the title & meta tags for SEO. I don't know if this is relevant to that

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to be on your homepage. If your homepage is just your latest posts, then it's fine to use index.php. If the homepage is static content or multiple lists of posts, perhaps separated by category, then you might want to use a custom page template.

Comment: Ah! That makes more sense - thank you so much!! So if I used another page for homepage (not index) would the index.php become the all-posts blog page basically?